# URL Rewrite back reference action URL not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I  have setup a url rewrite rule to redirect from one domain to another in case matching the condition. i have a site abc.aaa.com which should redirect to abc.bbb.com if url matches with *.aaa.com. When I hard code the action URL its working fine but using back reference its not working.
I am using IIS 8.5

Below are the rules.
This is not working. When I am doing this URL is showing http://abc.aaa.com/abc.bbb.com

```
<rule name="Redirect aaa.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).aaa.com(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}.bbb.com{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This is working

```
<rule name="Redirect aaa.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).aaa.com(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc.bbb.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I have tried the same pattern in rule pattern and same action without condition. thats also not working

```
<rule name="Redirect aaa.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*).aaa.com(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc.bbb.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: `{C:1}` does not contain `http://`. If you do some troubleshooting, it should be clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks Lex Li. You are correct. I realized it later that {C:1} doesn't have http://, then later fixed the issue.

Comment: Post your findings as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that {C:1} doesn't contain http:// part and seperated that in URL action . it's working fine.Below is the modified rule
Thanks Lex Li for the quick response

```
<rule name="Redirect aaa.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).aaa.com(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}.bbb.com{PATH_INFO}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```